# Group of variables vs dictionary

Tags: performance, dictionary

So, I was looking at how to create an array in batch, and noticed that one way of going about it could allow an associative array like structure. Which made me wonder, would a bunch of variables give the same access time and perform the same as a dictionary, but without the hashing?

For example, would:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5
```

have the same lookup time as a dictionary with the same values? However, wouldn't a group of variables get around the issue of having to use a hash function to determine the storage location of the variable? Would this be dependent on the language and how it deals with variables and objects?

Okay, so to try to be clearer, say you have the following code:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5
f = 6
g = 7
h = 8

dictionary = {
    "a":1,
    "b":2,
    "c":3,
    "d":4,
    "e":5,
    "f":6,
    "g":7,
    "h":8
}

print a + b
print dictionary["a"] + dictionary["b"]
```

making the dictionary object would require the use of a hashing function to determine the location for the stored variables. The would further require lookup time to access those variables. Thus, wouldn't it take marginally longer and use more storage to store the dictionary vs the 8 variables? Another related question: do storage locations for variables themselves use hashing?

Comment: Your question makes almost no sense.  Please give specific code example of what you want compare.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup times on hashed dictionaries are longer than straight variable lookup.

However, they are still *pretty fast* and are most welcomed for dynamically structured objects.

In the case of batch scripting, this would not really matter. Both are quite slow in comparison of other languages.